# Database.update issue with AccessLevel (FLS check) and Master-Detail fields with reparenting disabled

Tags: master-detail, database, fls, record-access-level

I'm having an issue with using `AccessLevel.User_mode`:

`Database.update(someSObject, AccessLevel.User_mode);`

The problem is that if I have a Master-detail field on an object that is being updated and that field has reparenting disabled, then even if my user has full access to the field, I'm still getting the error "Operation failed due to fields being inaccessible on Sobject..." because the field is not updateable due to reparenting setting.

If I enable reparenting then everything is working fine. I understand that I could just remove the field from the SObject just before the update but that is a workaround that adds to heap size and something that should not be required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Security.stripInaccessible](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_with_security_stripInaccessible.htm) method to efficiently remove fields that can't be updated. Note that there's no way to "clear" a field once its set, aside from using the `clear()` method, which would reset all fields. This method can deal with heap efficiently, because you can just assign the results to the input parameter:

```
records = Security.stripInaccessible(AccessType.UPDATABLE, records).getRecords();
```

This one-liner will never increase heap or trip the governor limit, and if fields are removed, will actually decrease overall heap usage.

Comment: Unfortunately this doe's not help with my issue since it will effectively remove any fields that my user simply lacks permissions to (regardless if they are missing the permission due to reparenting being disabled or the field not being set on his profile). This would defeat the purpose of using AccessLevel.User_mode.

By clearing I meant creating a clone of a record and setting the same values for all fields except if that field is a master-detail with reparenting disabled. I already have a method for that but it's a workaround and not something i want to use long term.

Comment: @LinQ On the flip side, users shouldn't be updating fields they don't have access to, which is the point of "user mode." Still, if this is off the table, your proposed workaround should still be fairly performant, at least in small volumes.